# Two header with own line item in one display

Tags: abap

I got a request from user to develop a report that show the invoice detail in one display.

All I found was how to show two different tables in the same page.

Is there a way to show it in the same table but with two header?

It's something like this.

> HD    Billing Doc.    Doc. Currency   Sales Org   Distr. Channel  Billing Date
>
> IT    Item    Billed qty  Sales unit  Net weight  Net value
>
> HD    900230006   USD JH01    01  05.01.2014
>
> IT    10  60  KG  60  1000
>
> IT    20  20  BAG 20  4000
>
> HD    900230007   EUR JH01    01  05.01.2014
>
> IT    10  22  KG  22  990
>
> IT    20  67  BAG 67  456
>
> IT    30  15  KG  15  897

Answer (score 2):

You can use ALV functionality to do this.

> You can use the ALV object model to apply tables in three different
>   ways:
>
> - as a simple, two-dimensional table ( CL_SALV_TABLE class)
> - as a hierarchically-sequential table
> - The following paragraphs relate to this table. as a tree structure ( CL_SALV_TREE class)

See program SALV_DEMO_TREE_SIMPLE or SALV_DEMO_HIERSEQ_SIMPLE in package SALV_OM_OBJECTS as an examples. The class documentation is also pretty good.

---

Alternatively you can try using function module REUSE_ALV_HIERSEQ_LIST_DISPLAY, but this is older functionality

> Functionality This module outputs two internal tables as a formated
>   hierarchical-sequential list.
>
> Principle:
>
> - Pass an internal table containing the set of header information to be output.
> - Pass an internal table containing the set of item information to be output.
> - Pass a structure containing the general list layout details
> - Pass a field catalog in the form of an internal table. The field catalog describes the fields to be output in the list.

See program BCALV_TEST_HIERSEQ_LIST in package SLIS as an example.